# Set Tick Label Font Properties from other axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using twiny() to create a second x-axis above a figure, and set the tick labels explicitly. After doing this, the font properties of this second x-axis doesn't match the rest of the figure. How can I get them to match?

Here is how I create the second axis:

```
topXaxis = ax.twiny()
topXaxis.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
topXaxis.set_xticklabels(new_tick_numbers)
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I've tried things like this, but nothing happens:

```
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
l = labels[0]
props = l.get_fontproperties()
for label in topXaxis.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(props)
```

How can I set the top x-axis to have the same font-properties as the bottom one?

Comment: you can use `rc` here. like `plt.rc('font', family='serif', size='12.0')`

Comment: can you then write the entire code that produces the above plot? It would be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a common font throughout your graph/plot you can use the `rc params` [(You can find more documentation here)](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc) and set a common font and fontsize.

Example:

`plt.rc('font', family='serif', size='12.0')`

Once you set this at the beginning, throughout your entire code, all the characters will have the font `serif` and a common fontsize.

You can find more font's and other properties that can be changed using `rc params`.

Comment: I already set the rc params, see the edit of my original post. Somehow, it does not affect all the text in my plot. If I remove my function and call only plt.rc like you suggest, the font works, but everything else I want breaks.

Comment: what are the other things that "break"? your question was to have a common labelfont.

Comment: What I meant was: I want to set the font without removing the existing functionality in the function called "latexPlot". I just found out that the rc param "'text.usetex': True" is what breaks the code and gives me different fonts on different axes. I use it in order to render LaTeX math in my figures, but the LaTeX seems to work without it... Any clue why?

Comment: Since you answered my original question, before I found the real cause of my problem, I will mark this question as answered and start a new thread. Thank you for your help.